# Login system using c++

Tags: c++, oop, authentication

I tried a login system, but it doesn't recognize any username from any user of the user's vector, which includes user objects from class user; I wanted to use strings to introduce values to compare with the user's information, but I don't know how to compare char* with string, because, in User class, I need to write username and password using char*;

```
class User{

private:

char *username;
char *password;
int age;

public:
User(){}
User(char *,char *p, int a){...}
~User();
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, User &u);
char* getUsername(){ return username};
char* getPassword(){return password};
};

void Log(User users[])
{
int nrusers = 3;
char * entereduser;
char *enteredpass;
char buffer[20];

cout << "username: ";
entereduser = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];
strcpy(enterduser, buffer);
cin >> entereduser;
cout << "password: ";
enteredpass = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];
strcpy(enteredpass, buffer);
cin >> enteredpass;
for (int i = 0; i < nrusers; i++)
{
    if (entereduser == users[i].getUsername())
    {
        if (entereduser == users[i].getPassword())
        {
            cout << "Authentication successful!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            AuthenticationMenu(users);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Wrong password!" << endl;
            cout << endl;
            int opt;
            cout << "Try again" << endl;
            cout << "Go to first page" << endl;
            cout << "Enter you option: ";
            cin >> opt;
            switch (opt)
            {
            case 1:
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                Log(users);
                break;
            case 2:
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                AuthenticationMenu(users);
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Choose from 1 to 2: ";
                cin >> opt;
            }

        }

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Wrong username" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        int opt;
        cout << "Try again" << endl;
        cout << "Go to first page" << endl;
        cout << "Enter you option: ";
        cin >> opt;
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 1:
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Log(users);
            break;
        case 2:
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            AuthenticationMenu(users);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Choose from 1 to 2: ";
            cin >> opt;
        }

    }
}

void main()
{
User u2("Jamie15","t3456",20);
User u3("Chris","fgh6",22);

User users[2]={u2,u3};

Log(users);

}
```

I tried to change char *entereduser and char* enteredpass with string entereduser and string enteredpass, but I don't know how to compare after this..What should I change to make my function recognize username and password from any user in the vector?

AuthenticationMenu() is another function of the entire code, I need to redirect to it

Comment: There's a world of difference between `==` and `strcmp`; anyway, in C++, you should be using `std::string`.

Comment: ‘*User class, I need to write username and password using `char*`’* No. No you don't. Just use `std::string`.

Comment: Who says that you need to use `char*`?

Comment: You should also use `std::vector<User> const& users` instead of `User users[]`.

Comment: I'm in university and for the moment we need to use in coding what they want, not what we want. So does anyone knows what should I change using this kind of writing the code?

Comment: use strcmp() to compare the strings. OR if you are not allowed to modify the code as you are in university attach a debugger and overwrite the JNE-opcode to NOP, so the authentication will be successful.

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare C strings with `operator==`, you have to use [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp). Using `==` on 2 pointers only compares their addresses.

**But** since you're using C++ stop using C strings (and `new`) all together and start using `std::string`.